# Trouble with RAND_MAX

Tags: c, random

This simple code:

```
int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));

   const int size = rand() % RAND_MAX;
   int numbers[size];

   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      numbers[i] = rand() % RAND_MAX;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      printf("numbers[%d]=%d\n", i, numbers[i]);
}
```

doesn't compile because the size of array isn't `const` value.

Why does that happen?

How can I fix it?

Comment: `rand() % RAND_MAX` is pointless. Since the range of numbers returned by `rand()` is `0..RAND_MAX`, it does nothing but convert the highest value, `RAND_MAX`, to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

With `ANSI C89` and `C90` standard, you have to know the size of the array in advance at compile time. Only in `C99` is it allowed for variable sized arrays.

You can either compile it with a `c99` compiler or you could allocate memory on the heap:

```
int *numbers = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

On older compilers defining the length of an array with a variable i.e. not a constant is prohibited.
Use the [`malloc()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) function instead:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
const int size = rand() % RAND_MAX;
int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(*numbers)*size);
```

Comment: `sizeof(numbers)` gives the size of a pointer, not the size of type `int`.